# Yum: failing to downgrade / undo changes

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, uninstall

So I did *yum update* last night because I decided that I should update whatever packages I could. Big mistake.

Now I can't undo the changes, and it's not telling me why. I am trying to undo 65 (as shown via *yum history*):

```
   ID | Login user          | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
   65 | My User <guy>       | 2016-12-08 18:07 | I, O, U        |  800 EE
   64 | My User <guy>       | 2016-12-08 17:44 | Erase          |    1   
   63 | My User <guy>       | 2016-12-08 17:29 | Update         |    1
```

So I do *yum history undo 65*. And at first it looks okay, giving me stuff that looks like:

```
Updated     ConsoleKit-0.4.1-3.el6.x86_64                                  @anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5
Update                 0.4.1-6.el6.x86_64                                  @base
Updated     ConsoleKit-libs-0.4.1-3.el6.x86_64                             @anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5
Update                      0.4.1-6.el6.x86_64                             @base
Updated     ConsoleKit-x11-0.4.1-3.el6.x86_64                              @anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5
Update                     0.4.1-6.el6.x86_64                              @base
Updated     NetworkManager-1:0.8.1-66.el6.x86_64                           @anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5
Update                     1:0.8.1-107.el6.x86_64                          @base
Updated     NetworkManager-glib-1:0.8.1-66.el6.x86_64                      @anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5
Update                          1:0.8.1-107.el6.x86_64                     @base
Updated     NetworkManager-gnome-1:0.8.1-66.el6.x86_64                     @anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64/6.5
Update                           1:0.8.1-107.el6.x86_64                    @base
```

But after all of that it's nothing but:

```
Failed to downgrade: ConsoleKit-0.4.1-3.el6.x86_64
Failed to downgrade: ConsoleKit-libs-0.4.1-3.el6.x86_64
Failed to downgrade: ConsoleKit-x11-0.4.1-3.el6.x86_64
Failed to downgrade: 1:NetworkManager-0.8.1-66.el6.x86_64
Failed to downgrade: 1:NetworkManager-glib-0.8.1-66.el6.x86_64
Failed to downgrade: 1:NetworkManager-gnome-0.8.1-66.el6.x86_64
...
Error: No package(s) available to install
```

And it doesn't tell me why or what to try so I am lost. When I try *yum downgrade x-package* it tells me "Only Upgrade available on package: x-package".

Edit 2: If it had worked, I should have seen yum action 66 shouldn't I?

Answer (score 3):

1) Download all the packages for which the message `Failed to downgrade` is displayed. You can use centos [vault url](http://vault.centos.org/) for the rpms.

2) Put all the rpms in a directory ( say `/tmp/yum_repo_test/`)

3) Create a local repository
    `createrepo --update /tmp/yum_repo_test/`

4) Create a file `/etc/yum.repos.d/temp.repo` with the following content:

```
[temp-local]
name=temp Repository
baseurl=file:/tmp/yum_repo_test
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

5) Clean and update `yum` cache
    `yum clean all && yum makecache fast`

6) Revert `yum` updates
    `yum history undo 65`

And yes if the undo is successful another transaction id is created.

Comment: vault repo isn't very useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
yum clean all
yum downgrade <rpm name> -y
```

Comment: doesn't work for me :-(